# Google maps being loaded multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

In my page: http://sitesdemo.mghospedagem.com/ivam-entregas/3/33209.html

I tried disabling a few javascript related to Google Maps, but Chrome Console is still pointing me the same errors, saying I have multiple instances of Google maps loaded.

I'm getting errors like not calculating the shipping, or not being able to use the map, blah blah blah.

Can anyone help me find what part of the javascript I have to edit to fix this?

Here is the log:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

```
main.js:61 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
main.js:60 You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.main.js:60 yl
33209.html:9 Uncaught ReferenceError: J is not defined
VM603:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'geometry' of undefined
33209.html:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: J is not defined
33209.html:9 Uncaught ReferenceError: J is not defined
33209.html:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: J is not defined
33209.html:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: J is not defined
http://sitesdemo.mghospedagem.com/ivam-entregas/3/33209/css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Here the javascript file described on the log:
https://jsfiddle.net/x24e2px2

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue **in the question itself** (not a link to a problem page or other external resource), the question should stand alone if any links provided go dead.

Comment: Too many stuff to post. It's intuitive. Sometimes the map works, sometimes not, and at the same time, the same happens to the calcs on the right side. Is it so hard to understand? Give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've obviously loaded some copies of some API-files from your own server, remove them:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="33209/js"></script><script src="33209/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: also remove all the other copies(from commons.js to stats.js) , the API must always be loaded from google's servers

Comment: Not for me... I see the map and will be asked for geolocation

Comment: Hey, thx, it solved the Google Maps problem! But I have to ask you now, remove the main.js and see it still works for you.

Comment: The only script that has to be loaded is http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false , all other API-related files(including main.js) will be loaded automatically when you load this file.

Comment: thx a lot. It definitely solved my problem. IT's funny because the first time I tested it, whatever I removed a script, I would get an error, perhaps it's because I wasn't removing all at once. God bless you, man.